# Unable to add key value pairs in Javascript dictionary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have some REACT code that generates a dictionary for me

My sample code is

```
var dict = []; // create an empty array

dict.push({
    key:   "keyName",
    value: "the value"
});
```

and my dictionary looks like this

```
{key: "2021-03-31", value: 1}
{key: "2021-03-26", value: 1}
{key: "2021-03-27", value: 1}
{key: "2021-03-26", value: 1}
{key: "2021-03-27", value: 1}
```

Now I am trying to implement a logic like this.

If a key exists in the dictionary then I want to increase the number in the value by 1, or else insert a new key-value pair in the dictionary

```
var xkey=<<some value>>
if (xkey in dict) {
    console.log("key found");
    dt[xkey] +=1
    }
else 
{ 
    dict.push(
        {key: xkey
            ,value: 1 })
}
```

My If the condition is always failing and the code gets into the else block every time, hence the values for all keys are set to 1 whereas, in my example here, two of the keys should have had the value equal to 2.

My dictionary should have become

```
 {key: "2021-03-31", value: 1}
 {key: "2021-03-26", value: 2}
 {key: "2021-03-27", value: 2}
```

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used Arrays and Objects in a mixed way. You can not acces an array elements by a key like you did. In other words you declared an Array not a Dictionory (called an Object in Javascript). The `in` operator only works aa s real members of the object `dict`.

Try this example:

```
var dict = {}; // create a map / object

...

var xkey=<<some key>>;

if (xkey in dict) 
{
    console.log("key found");
    dict[xkey] +=1
}
else 
{ 
    dict[xkey] = 1;
}
```

There is also a shorter way.

```
var dict = {}; // create a map / object    

...

var xkey=<<some key>>;

dict[xkey] = (xkey in dict) ? dict[xkey] + 1 : 1;
```

BTW your code is not compilable.

Answer (score 2):

`dict` is an array and you probably want to find a specific date by `key` of a specific object in the `dict` array for modifying it's value . For finding your specific object in the array you can use simple `find()` method

```
let array = [
    { key: "2021-03-31", value: 1 },
    { key: "2021-03-26", value: 1 },
    { key: "2021-03-27", value: 1 },
]

const myKey = '2021-03-26'

let goalObject = array.find(object => object.key === myKey)
goalObject ? goalObject.value++ : array.push({ key: myKey, value: 1 })
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to traverse to all records or else you can find an index and increase the value if the key is present. I have one solution maybe this will helps you to get your answer.

```
var dict = [];

function createDict(keyval) {
   if (dict.length === 0) {
      dict.push({
        key: keyval,
        value: 1
      })
   } else {
      const index = dict.findIndex(x => x.key === keyval);
      if (index > -1) {
        dict[index].value += 1;
      } else {
         dict.push({
            key: keyval,
            value: 1
         })
      }
   }
}

createDict("2021-03-31");
createDict("2021-03-26");
createDict("2021-03-27");
createDict("2021-03-26");
createDict("2021-03-27");

console.log(dict);
```

Final Results get like you want

```
[
  { key: '2021-03-31', value: 1 },
  { key: '2021-03-26', value: 2 },
  { key: '2021-03-27', value: 2 }
]
```

Comment: thanks Bhushi da, I understood my mistake now, but Peter's answer did the job for me, so marked it as the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

> if (xkey in dict)

This is the problem. here dict is an array. So if you will check that `x in dict` it will look at the keys of an array.

In JavaScript arrays are just type of objects with keys that goes from 0 to length of the array and one extra key is length.

Let's see in your example:
your dict is like this:

```js
dict = [
  {key: "2021-03-31", value: 1},
  {key: "2021-03-26", value: 1},
  {key: "2021-03-27", value: 1},
  {key: "2021-03-26", value: 1},
]
```

So if you run

```js
for(xkey in dict){
  console.log(xkey);
}
```

you will get output like this.

```
0
1
2
3
length
```

So if you check that `"1" in dict` then it will return true.

Solution to your problem might be look like this.

```js
func addValue(newValue){ // newValue is value to add if does not exist and increment if exists
  var isExist = false; 
  for(var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++){
    if(dict[i].key === newValue){
      dict[i].value++;
      isExist = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!isExist){
    dict.push({key: newValue, value: 1})
  }
}
```

More optimized solution is posted already by @Bhushi-da. This is for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks @phoenix, appreciate the detailed description.